# Suggest a JPA Unit test framework

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa

How to unit test JPA code? is there any way to generate Unit Test case itself?

Note: I am lazy and new to Unit Test code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this out, [Unitils](http://www.unitils.org/summary.html). Here is a [related discussion](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=50487), with some example codes.

Here is the example, showing [DBUnit, Spring and OpenJPA](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/bill/entry/20070428) together. You might not using all, but this can take you somewhere if you want to go with [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/), I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the middle of trying out OpenEJB (http://openejb.apache.org/) for my ongoing project. It's an embeddable container with support for EJB 3.0 (and partially 3.1). My first impression of it is fairly good.

Answer (score 1):

recently I faced a problem of testing:

1. business logic operating on JPA Entities
2. complex JPQL queries mixed with business logic.

I used [JPA-Unit](http://code.google.com/p/jpa-unit) and it solved all my problems.

Comment: didn't you write JPA-Unit yourself? :)